# Decimal representation in Mathematica 10

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation

I am using a slider to assign the value for a dynamic variable `x`, and want to display the value of `y=10^Dynamic@x` in decimal form. However, `y`, `N[y]`, or `NumberForm[y,1]` all display the output as `10^0` rather than `1` (for $y=0$, for example).

How do I force the output of $y$ to display in decimal form (in Mathematica 10.3)?

I understand M11.2 has the function `DecimalForm[ ]`, which may or may not work with dynamic variables.

Here is the code:

```
y = 10^Dynamic@x; {Slider[Dynamic[x], {-1, 1}], y}
```

Comment: `{Slider[Dynamic[x], {-1, 1}], Dynamic[y = 10^x]}` ?

Comment: @ilian Thanks. So Mathematica only evaluates the whole expression within the Dynamic function. I can then continue using the variable $y$ via `Dynamic@y`

Comment: Is `ClearAll[x, y];
y = 10^x;
{Slider[Dynamic[x], {-1, 1}], Dynamic[y]}` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Edmund Yes, indeed! Thks.